# Why am I getting wrong results when calling Func<int>?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code snippet in C#:

```
var actions = new List<Func<int>>();

IEnumerable<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (int value in values)
{
    actions.Add(() => value * value);
}

foreach (var action in actions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(action()); ;
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

It's running fine, but I am not getting the result I expect.

**Actual result**

9,9,9

**Expected result**

1,4,9

Why am I not getting the result I expect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're capturing the loop variable within your lambda expression, which means when the delegate is finally invoked, it's seeing the *final* value of the loop variable.

Simple fix:

```
foreach (int value in values)
{
    int copy = value;
    actions.Add(() => copy * copy);
}
```

This way you get a new `copy` variable in each iteration of the loop, so each delegate expression will capture a different variable, and they're not affected by the loop variable (`value`) changing over time.

Eric Lippert explains this well in ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) (and [part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)).

Basically this is a "gotcha" in C# which nearly everyone falls for sooner or later.

Comment: I have one doubt,this gotcha is only for generic delegate or for normal delegate also.

Comment: @geek: Any delegate created using an anonymous function (anonymous method or lambda expression) - it's about how variables are captured, not about generics.

Answer (score 13):

You need to capture the variable inside the loop. Right now your delayed execution actions are using the last value of `value` from the first `foreach` loop.

```
var actions = new List<Func<int>>();
        IEnumerable<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (int value in values)
        {
            var v = value;
            actions.Add(() => v * v);
        }
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(action()); ;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Note the `var v = value;` line.